# Non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: java, plsql

I'm getting error as

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

for a query in Eclipse but the same query is running fine in Toad.

I tried changing the date to `to_char`.

```
String query3 = "SELECT TXN_DATETIME FROM S3_ANTI_MONEY_LAUNDERING_TDS WHERE TRUNC(ROW_LOADED_DATE_TIME)='30-OCT-2018' AND SRC_FEED_NUM='63' AND BANK_ID IN('ISPP') AND SRC_RECORD_NUM IN('3','6')";

statement = connection.createStatement();
rs3 = statement.executeQuery(query3);

ArrayList<String> resultList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs3.next()) {
    String result = rs3.getString(1) ;
    resultList1.add(result);
```

Comment: What are the data types of the columns in `S3_ANTI_MONEY_LAUNDERING_TDS`?

Comment: Something isn't completely right here.  JDBC just passes your query string directly to Oracle (MySQL?), so if the above query works directly on your database, it should also work from your Java code.

Comment: can you please provide result of this query in eclipse: **select to_date('30-OCT-2018') from dual**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely the way that you have the date specified.

If you do not provide a proper date literal, then Oracle is using your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for the implicit conversion from text to date, and this might not be what you expect.

Replace this:

```
String query3 = "SELECT TXN_DATETIME FROM S3_ANTI_MONEY_LAUNDERING_TDS WHERE TRUNC(ROW_LOADED_DATE_TIME)='30-OCT-2018' AND SRC_FEED_NUM='63' AND BANK_ID IN('ISPP') AND SRC_RECORD_NUM IN('3','6')";
```

With this:

```
String query3 = "SELECT TXN_DATETIME FROM S3_ANTI_MONEY_LAUNDERING_TDS WHERE TRUNC(ROW_LOADED_DATE_TIME) = DATE '2018-10-30' AND SRC_FEED_NUM='63' AND BANK_ID IN('ISPP') AND SRC_RECORD_NUM IN('3','6')";
```

The proper way to do a DATE literal in Oracle is one of these:

`DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'`

`TIMESTAMP 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'`

Of course, you can use whatever mask you wish in this syntax:

`TO_DATE('2018-10-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

[Oracle docs for NLS_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-FC23EEEE-AA9F-4B3C-8CBB-888C9C0CA27F.htm#REFRN10119)

[Oracle docs for DATE and DATETIME literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062)

Finally, if your code is building that query on the fly, it's much better to use bind variables and a prepared statement. Just make sure you are familiar with the nuances of Java dates and timestamps vs. Oracle dates and timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your database schema, I'd say this looks fishy:

```
SRC_RECORD_NUM IN('3','6')
```

I personally would NEVER declare a character field with a _NUM suffix, but your IN clause is passing character data. I bet you need to do:

```
SRC_RECORD_NUM IN (3,6)
```

But I'm guessing based entirely on the name of the field.